# Wrap multiple tags with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a python script that allow to convert a html doc into a [reveal.js](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/) slideshow. To do this, I need to wrap multiple tags inside a `<section>` tag.

It's easy to wrap a single tag inside another one using the [`wrap()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#wrap) method. However I can't figure out how I can wrap multiple tags.

An example for clarification, the original html:

```
html_doc = """
<html>

<head>
  <title>The Dormouse's story</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="first-paragraph">First paragraph</h1>
  <p>Some text...</p>
  <p>Another text...</p>
  <div>
    <a href="http://link.com">Here's a link</a>
  </div>

  <h1 id="second-paragraph">Second paragraph</h1>
  <p>Some text...</p>
  <p>Another text...</p>

  <script src="lib/.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
"""


"""
```

I'd like to wrap the `<h1>` and their next tags inside `<section>` tags, like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>The Dormouse's story</title>
</head>
<body>

  <section>
    <h1 id="first-paragraph">First paragraph</h1>
    <p>Some text...</p>
    <p>Another text...</p>
    <div>
      <a href="http://link.com">Here's a link</a>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h1 id="second-paragraph">Second paragraph</h1>
    <p>Some text...</p>
    <p>Another text...</p>
  </section>

  <script src="lib/.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's how I made the selection:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import itertools
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
h1s = soup.find_all('h1')
for el in h1s:
    els = [i for i in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x.name not in [el.name, 'script'], el.next_elements)]
    els.insert(0, el)
    print(els)
```

Output:

```
[<h1 id="first-paragraph">First paragraph</h1>, 'First paragraph', '\n  ', <p>Some text...</p>, 'Some text...', '\n  ', <p>Another text...</p>, 'Another text...', '\n  ', <div><a href="http://link.com">Here's a link</a>  </div>, '\n    ', <a href="http://link.com">Here's a link</a>, "Here's a link", '\n  ', '\n\n  ']

[<h1 id="second-paragraph">Second paragraph</h1>, 'Second paragraph', '\n  ', <p>Some text...</p>, 'Some text...', '\n  ', <p>Another text...</p>, 'Another text...', '\n\n  ']
```

The selection is correct but I can't see how to wrap each selection inside a `<section>` tag.

Comment: Can you edit your post and show the expected output?

Comment: Please post expected output.

Comment: I added the explicit output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I found how to use the `wrap` method in that case. I needed to understand that **every change in the soup object is made in place**.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import itertools
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

# wrap all h1 and next siblings into sections
h1s = soup.find_all('h1')
for el in h1s:
    els = [i for i in itertools.takewhile(
              lambda x: x.name not in [el.name, 'script'],
              el.next_siblings)]
    section = soup.new_tag('section')
    el.wrap(section)
    for tag in els:
        section.append(tag)

print(soup.prettify())
```

This gives me the desired output. Hopes that's help.

Comment: Thank you.  I'd like to point out a few things I learned that may not be obvious.  1)  Attaching a tag someplace else (via append for example) removes it from its previous location.    2)  Because of (1) and because .next_siblings is a generator, not a list, you need to convert it to a list before iterating though the loop that calls section.append(tag),  Your complex `els=[...]` does that.   I didn't need the filtering, so I tried just `els=el.next_siblings`.   That fails because the first move of a sibling breaks the sibling chain.  `els=list(el.next_siblings)` works.

Answer (score 0):

i figured i'd weigh in on this one since its a bit difficult and confusing.  basically, using the html_test string that is BeautifulSoup'ed, I add a new div to the tree, anchor it on the  and then loop it, wrapping/appending in all elements, until it reaches , including nontagged strings.  the wrapTag function appends in all elements into the div until it reaches the last p.  the main thing to realize of that while loop is that appending to the div moves and not copies the next_sibling in.  so there would have been a shifting of the ith position if we'd use a hard list and for loop.  hope that helps.  lucas

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#coding: utf-8
from platform import python_version
from bs4 import __version__ as bs_version, Tag, NavigableString, BeautifulSoup

try:
    html_test = '<body><div class="div" id="1">beforePa<p>line 1a</p>betweenPab<p class="x">line 1b<b>bold in 1b</b></p>betweenPbc<p>line 1c</p>betweenPcd<p>line 1d</p>betweenPde<p class="y">line 1e</p>betweenPef<p>line 1f</p>afterPf</div><div class="div" id="2"><p>line 2a</p><p>line 2b</p><p>line 2c</p></div></body>'
    html = BeautifulSoup(html_test, 'lxml')
    print(html.prettify())
    parser = 'lxml'
except:
    parser = 'html.parser'
print('python: "'+python_version()+'", bs4 version: "'+bs_version+'", bs4 parser: "'+parser+'"')

def p(tag, sstr=""):
    print(sstr+".. .")
    print(tag, " ... ", type(tag))
    print("text: ", tag.text, " ... ", type(tag.text))
    print("string: ", tag.string, " ... ", type(tag.string))
    print("contents: ", tag.contents, " ... ", type(tag.contents))
    print()
    return

def newTag(tag, attrs={}, tstr=""):
    n = html.new_tag(tag)
    if (len(attrs) > 0):
        for k, v in attrs.items():
            n[k] = v
    if (len(tstr) > 0):
        n.string = tstr
    return n

def wrapTag(newTag, fromTagInclusive, toTagExclusive):
    fromTagInclusive.wrap(newTag)
    #p(fromTagInclusive.parent, "fromTag.parent")
    n = fromTagInclusive.parent
    c = 0
    while 1:
        c += 1
        x = n.next_sibling
        if (x is None):
            break
        n.append(x)
        #print(c, x, n.next_sibling, isinstance(n.next_sibling, Tag), n.next_sibling.name if isinstance(n.next_sibling, Tag) else "~Tag", n.next_sibling.attrs if isinstance(n.next_sibling, Tag) else "~Tag")
        #if isinstance(n.next_sibling, Tag) and (n.next_sibling.name == 'p') and ('class' in n.next_sibling.attrs) and ('y' in n.next_sibling['class']):
        if (n.next_sibling == toTagExclusive):
            break
    return n, toTagExclusive

n = newTag('div', { 'class':"classx", 'id':"idx" }, 'here we are in classx idx')
p(n, "new div")
n, _ = wrapTag(n, html.find('p', {'class':"x"}), html.find('p', {'class':"y"}))
p(n, "wrapped div")
print(html.prettify())
exit()
```