# beautiful soup combine tags with the same name

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have multiple Title Tags and I would like to combine them into one Title Tag. Below is what I have: (I want to combine Title Tags so that when i print soup the tags are together & I don't want them to become strings)

```
<title>
  <b> Title Name 1 </b>
</title> 
<title>
  Title Name 2
</title>
```

This is my desired output:

```
<title>
  <b> Title Name 1 </b> Title Name 2
</title>
```

This is what I have tried doing so far:
I created a new tag and then trying to add all title tags into that so then I could later unwrap Title Tag and be left with a single tag:

```
<title>
  <b> Title Name 1 </b>
</title> 
<title>
  Title Name 2
</title>
<final-title>
</final-title>


for item in soup.findAll(['title', 'final-title']):
    if item.name == 'final-title':
        text = item
    if item.name == 'title':
        text.insert(len(text.contents),item)
```

However this method does not grab the approrite title names because I have a lot of these title tags. I have also tried using soemthing similar to this ([Wrap multiple tags with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274222/wrap-multiple-tags-with-beautifulsoup))

Comment: My idea is to extract tags to a list and divide same to many sublist by their class/id/... , then rebuild file.

Comment: but in my case I have mutliple title tags in this order and not all title tags should combine together. so example title 1 & 2 go together but 3&4 would go together and not be in combinated of 1&2

Answer (score 0):

to use `.insert()` you need to convert string to `list()` but I think it easier to just create list innerHTML of `<title>` with `.encode_contents()`, then combine it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_raw = '''<title>
  <b> Title Name 1 </b>
</title> 
<title>Title Name 2</title>
<final-title>
</final-title>
'''
title = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_raw, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll(['title', 'final-title']):
    if item.name == 'title':
        title.append(item.encode_contents().strip())

combinedTitle = '<title>%s</title>' % ' '.join(title)

print combinedTitle
# output
# <title><b> Title Name 1 </b> Title Name 2</title>
```

Comment: thank you ! this gives me an idea on how to move forward

Comment: you're welcome, please consider mark this answer as correct.

Comment: is there a way to combine them so when I print soup it shows the combined results?

Comment: as far as I know, no other way